# Intellij 2017.1.5 with node8 remote debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea

I just installed Node 8.1.3, and upgraded intellij to latest 2017.1.5 ultimate edition. trying out the nodejs remote debugger using the following command:

`node --inspect-brk --harmony application.js`

got the following output:

`Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/4b404a2a-5d16-4a0a-ba64-b1e2b6504fcf
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector`

Setup the intellij remote debugger with localhost 127.0.0.1 and port 9229, but connection didn't seem to be established. i see there is a token like value after the link from the output, was wondering if i need to add that value in intellij nodejs remote debugger setting somewhere?

Any suggestions or help are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, [WEB-27559](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27559) is fixed in 2017.2

Please note that [Node.js Remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) Run configuration can only be used when debugging with TCP-based Protocol (**Node.js** < **7.x**).

To remotely debug application with Chrome Debugging Protocol (with `--inspect`/`--inspect-brk`), you need using [Chromium Remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-chromium-remote.html) Run configuration.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#remote_debugging

Comment: not fixed, remote debugging does not work in 2017.2.5

Comment: please provide the details here - or, better, create a ticket in youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: I created a ticket today already. Problem was I used `Node.js Remote Debugging` which works with old 6.x version only with `--debug` switch, switched to `Chromium Remote` configuration (it was not clear to me it is built in IntelliJ) which works fine with node 8.x. Good to extend Your answer so people can understand how to correctly create remote debugging configuration in IntelliJ.